# Can I uninstall and then immediately reinstall the Ubuntu printer driver

Tags: drivers, printing

I am warned that if I uninstall the Ubuntu printer driver future updates will not include new items in the Ubuntu desktop system set. I don't wish to miss out. Still, several printer projects have failed even though the cause, a printer jam, has been cleared. If I can immediately reinstall the Ubuntu printer driver I figure I shouldn't miss out. If I can't I guess I will. That would be a bummer.

Comment: I think you should rephrase the question. It's very difficult to understand. Is it possible that you're worried about removing the ubuntu-desktop meta package?

Comment: Jo-Erlend, If I go to the Ubuntu Software Center and navigate to the Printing installation; highlight it and press the Remove button I receive this message: If you uninstall Printing, future updates will not include new items in the Ubuntu desktop system set. Are you sure you want to continue? It doesn't mention removing anything. It does suggest a downside: missing out on new features. I'd rather not. If I can uninstall and then reinstall the Ubuntu printer driver I shouldn't. I don't know if the Ubuntu desktop system set and the Ubuntu desktop meta package are one in the same. Are they?

Answer (score 0):

What this means is that you're removing a package which the ubuntu-desktop meta package depends on. This meta-package doesn't contain anything by itself, but sets a set of requirements that will be automatically downloaded.

If you remove the ubuntu-desktop package and then want to upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu, this package will not be upgraded so if a new package is added in the new version, it won't be automatically installed because nothing requires it.

In your case, it's perfectly safe to remove it and if you want to reinstall it, just install the ubuntu-desktop package, which will then also reinstall the printing package.

Comment: Jo-Erlend, I tried fixing the printer problem by uninstalling and re installing the Ubuntu printer driver. The uninstall must have failed because the new copy  wasn't new. It required no setup. It was setup for my printer. It generated the same error message and it did not print. If it quacks like a duck it's a duck. I won't be using that driver again. Maybe, if I had re installed the printer driver by re installing the Ubuntu-desktop package as you suggest I would have gotten a different result. I will never know.

Comment: I don't know what printer you have or if you should install anything at all, why you did so, etc. You asked if you could uninstall something without breaking your system and I answered that question. By the way, I always recommend HP printers. They're the best one out there with regards to drivers. They're quite simply in a class of its own.